# CSS selectors, tagname + class vs class

Tags: css

Lets imagine very simple case:

```
div.className{}
```

vs

```
.className{}
```

Which option is faster and why ?

Comment: ps. I've made some bet with my boss about this, and I hope I will win this beer ;-)

Comment: according to me second option is best and fast as it will directly go to that element which has .className class no matter its span or div or other but in first case it will only go to those div who has .className class and it will search all div inner child too. PS you can't measure the speed as both are not human testable..:p

Comment: @Leothelion i disagree. see https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Comment: @op whether or not it is faster in your case should depend on how many elements there are in the page that are *not* divs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.className{}` is faster in downloading, because of smaller size of the css file.

It is also faster when rendering page, because it is not necessary to look for `div` elements.

A guideline from [google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml#Type_Selectors):

> Avoid qualifying ID and class names with type selectors. Unless
>   necessary (for example with helper classes), do not use element names
>   in conjunction with IDs or classes.
>
> Avoiding unnecessary ancestor selectors is useful for [performance reasons](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/) .

Comment: "It is also faster when rendering page" do you have any reference for this?

Answer (score 1):

One very important difference between `div.classname` and simply `.classname` is in something called [selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity). It is a set of rules which defines which selector gets more weight once the browser starts going through all the selectors that potentially have influence on a particular element.

ne of the most basic rules of CSS is that selectors can be redefined in a way that whatever definition comes last and has influence on a particular element its the one that is going to be used (the sole exception being when using !important which always takes precedence).

Now in the above example redefining the .class selector should actually hide the text but instead its still visible. How is that possible if we said that latter rules always take precedence? Its because the div.classname rule has a higher specificity that .box since it actually gets points for containing both an element (div) and a class selector (.class) in its selector declaration (div.class).

Of course the div.class rule will be applied only on a div element but since class selectors are often reusable pieces of code there is plenty of situations when they are used on divs.

Although the rules in the official W3 specification are not that hard to understand they are sometimes pretty hard to remember. That's why I would like to recommend an excellent article on CSS selector specificity which can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

In my opinion selector specificity is by far the most important thing to master when it comes to tracing inheritance problems with CSS stylesheets.

[For Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BN8Zk/)

[Find some more info](http://roytomeij.com/blog/2012/dont-use-class-names-to-find-HTML-elements-with-JS.html)

[Follow Up](http://roytomeij.com/blog/2012/follow-up-don-t-use-class-names-to-find-html-elements-with-js.html)

Comment: I do know concept of the selector specifity, as this is one of primary concepts in CSS, but is this selector specifity has any impact on CSS perfomance in general ? Some links maybe?